# Installation failed: DB Error:connect failed

Tags: installation

I'd appreciate any hint on how to fix this: wordpress installed, civicrm installation fails with
Initialization Error code 24 DB Error: connect failed. Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

wordpress successfully uses the same database and user, therefore i can't figure out why access is denied for civicrm installer at some point (database has entries for civicrm, but installation is not completed.
thanks

Comment: Hi. Could use a bit more info. If there are some civicrm tables in your DB, then clearly the DB access credentials are OK, or nothing would get written there. So it's probably something else getting in the way. What's your hosting environment?

Comment: Hi Graham, thank you. Debian bullseye with apache 2, mariadb 10.5, php 7.4, wordpress 5.7. . your comment makes sense to me, but the error message stills says "access denied".

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if this is due to the authentication method that is not set to native password. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Try this:

```
ALTER USER 'YOUR_CIVI_DB_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD_OF_THE_CIVI_DB_USER';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it might have been that. I changed the passwort by another method and it does work now.